# sess.run dynamically increases memory usage

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory

I tried to train my model by following code.

```
sess.run([train_op, model.global_step, model.loss, model.prediction], feed_dict)
```

But, I found memory usage increase dynamically when I ran "model.prediction".

I never keep results of "sess.run()" during iteration.

"model.prediction" is

```
@property
def prediction(self):
    return [tf.argmax(self.logits_b, 1),
            tf.argmax(self.logits_m, 1),
            tf.argmax(self.logits_s, 1),
            tf.argmax(self.logits_d, 1)]
```

I don't know why this happened.
Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you use the property `prediction` you are creating new operations in the graph. You should create the operations only once beforehand and return them in the property:

```
def create_model(self):
    # Hypothetical function that creates the model, only called once
    # ...
    self._prediction = (tf.argmax(self.logits_b, 1),
                        tf.argmax(self.logits_m, 1),
                        tf.argmax(self.logits_s, 1),
                        tf.argmax(self.logits_d, 1))
    # ...

@property
def prediction(self):
    return self._prediction
```